# Why does dropwhile and takewhile skip the last a?

Tags: python, python-itertools

Why does `dropwhile` and `takewhile` skip the last `a` in the following exmaple?

```
>>> import itertools
>>> s = "Aardvark"
>>> def vowel(c):
...     return c.lower() in "aeiou"
...
>>> list(itertools.dropwhile(vowel, s))
['r', 'd', 'v', 'a', 'r', 'k']
>>> list(itertools.takewhile(vowel, s))
['A', 'a']
```

Before test in console, I think the result should be `['r', 'd', 'v', 'r', 'k']` and `['A', 'a', 'a']`.

The documentation said the roughly implementation of `dropwhile` and `takewhile` as follows:

```
def dropwhile(predicate, iterable):
# dropwhile(lambda x: x<5, [1,4,6,4,1]) --> 6 4 1
iterable = iter(iterable)
for x in iterable:
    if not predicate(x):
        yield x
        break
for x in iterable:
    yield x

def takewhile(predicate, iterable):
    # takewhile(lambda x: x<5, [1,4,6,4,1]) --> 1 4
    for x in iterable:
        if predicate(x):
            yield x
        else:
            break
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not **filtering** the string, you are **dropping or taking** as a certain condition is maintained.

The drop-while would stop dropping when reaching `"r"` which is not a vowel, and take the rest, and the take-while would stop taking when reaching `"r"` which is not a vowel, and drop the rest.

The behavior you are describing as desired can be gained with `filter`:

```
>>> list(filter(lambda x: x.lower() in 'aeoui', "Aardvark"))
['A', 'a', 'a']
>>> list(filter(lambda x: x.lower() not in 'aeoui', "Aardvark"))
['r', 'd', 'v', 'r', 'k']
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting at the beginning, it `take`s items `While` they match a condition, and stops when they don’t. You’re looking for [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) (and [`itertools.filterfalse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.filterfalse)):

```
list(filter(vowel, s))
```

or a list comprehension:

```
[c for c in s if vowel(c)]
```